# How to add custom icons to solution explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, icons, visual-studio-extensions, solution-explorer

I am trying to add custom icons to the solution explorer in Visual Studio, the same way the [FileIcons extension](https://github.com/madskristensen/FileIcons) does.

I think I've done everything right for Visual Studio to associate the new icon with files ending with the `.d` and `.di` extensions, but Visual Studio still doesn't show any icon in the solution explorer.

Here is the manifest generated with `ManifestFromResources.exe`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file was generated by the ManifestFromResources tool.-->
<!-- Version: 14.0.50929.2 -->
<ImageManifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/ImageManifestSchema/2014">
  <Symbols>
    <String Name="Resources" Value="/VisualDLS;Component/Icons" />
    <Guid Name="AssetsGuid" Value="{872b4702-eabf-444b-b6b3-96dc64531f74}" />
    <ID Name="d" Value="0" />
  </Symbols>
  <Images>
    <Image Guid="$(AssetsGuid)" ID="$(d)">
      <Source Uri="$(Resources)/d.png">
        <Size Value="32" />
      </Source>
    </Image>
  </Images>
  <ImageLists />
</ImageManifest>
```

Here is the pkgdef file:

```
[$RootKey$\ShellFileAssociations\.d]
"DefaultIconMoniker"="872b4702-eabf-444b-b6b3-96dc64531f74:0"
[$RootKey$\ShellFileAssociations\.di]
"DefaultIconMoniker"="872b4702-eabf-444b-b6b3-96dc64531f74:0"
```

In my extension's vsixmanifest, the pkgdef file is defined as an asset with the following properties:

- Type: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage`
- Source: `File on filesystem`
- Path: `icons.pkgdef` (which is, obviously, how I named my pkgdef file)

Regarding file properties, the icon image file is set as a resource, while the image manifest and the pkgdef file are both set as content to be included in the VSIX.

If I try to use a KnownMoniker instead in my image manifest, Visual Studio picks it up correctly and displays the icon properly; and I can even reference icon monikers from the FileIcons extension if I install it beforehand. But as soon as I try to use my own manifest and icon, nothing shows up.
I'm probably doing something wrong here, but I can't seem to see what exactly.

Comment: Ed Provided some suggestions for custom icon in solution explorer before, if possible, you could check it here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a535a72a-8953-430a-84e6-5618e488f7c3/custom-file-type-icons-in-solution-explorer-part-3?forum=vsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who could randomly stumble upon the same problem in the future, I found what my issue was. During my initial tests, I must have done something wrong, leading Visual Studio to show no icon in the explorer next to the `.d` files.
Afterwards, it probably continued doing so because of an icon cache somewhere, even after correcting whatever I had done wrong. After renaming the file with another extension, and then renaming it back to its original name, the new icon started showing up.